# Android WebView Behavior for open DeepLinks

Tags: android, webview

I've an App, in which there is WebView. When I try to open any Universal link/Deep Link available on the web page loaded in the WebView it should open the targeted app but it open inside the WebView.
and yes I've implemented the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` like below from `WebViewClient()`.

```
   override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): 
   Boolean {
       view.loadUrl(request.uri.toString())
       return true
   }
```

The behavior I wanting is if user clicks on any normal URL it should open inside WebView and if there is any Universal Link or any Deep Link, it should open the targeted app like all browser apps are doing.

Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution on Android Developer page at [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#let-non-browser-apps-handle-urls)

and now the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` block look like below

```
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest):Boolean {
   val url = request.url.toString()
   try {
       val intent = Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).apply {
           // The URL should either launch directly in a non-browser app (if it's
          // the default), or in the disambiguation dialog.
          addCategory(CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
          flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER
       }
       startActivity(intent)
   } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
       // Only browser apps are available, or a browser is the default.
       // So you can open the URL directly in your app, for example in a
       view.loadUrl(url)
   }
   
   return true
}
```

Hope this will helpful for other...